# Website does not recognize my inputs [how to fire IE dom event manually from VBA]

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, dom-events

I woud like to buy on gdax automatically. But my inputs in the Amount window doesn´t get recognized. I can see that on the little field, that says: `Total (LTC) ≈ 0.00000000`

My code:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim ObjIE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim Ohtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLtags As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLtag As IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLobjekt As IHTMLElement
    Dim item_limit As Object
    Dim y As Integer

    With ObjIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set Ohtml = .document
    End With

    'Amount
    Do
        Set HTMLtags = Ohtml.getElementsByClassName("OrderForm_input-box_XkGmi")
        DoEvents
    Loop While HTMLtags.Length = 0
    For Each HTMLtag In HTMLtags
        If HTMLtag.Children(1).innerText = "EUR" Then
            Set HTMLobjekt = HTMLtag.Children(0)
            HTMLobjekt.Value = 100      ' this is the part that i excanged
        End If
    Next HTMLtag

    'get the Total(LTC) to cross check
    Do
        Set HTMLtags = Ohtml.getElementsByClassName("OrderForm_total_6EL8d")
        DoEvents
    Loop While HTMLtags.Length = 0
    For Each HTMLtag In HTMLtags
        Debug.Print HTMLtag.innerText & "Total(LTC)"
    Next HTMLtag

End Sub
```

This is what the website says when the code is done:

[image: Picture.this is how it is]

and this is how it should look like, and looks when I type the number in manually:

[image: Picture.this is how it should be]

I also exchange the marked part with things like:

```vb
HTMLobjekt.innerText = 100
```

or

```vb
HTMLobjekt.innerText = "100"
```

or

```vb
HTMLobjekt.Value = "100"
```

but nothing worked.

Comment: From browser developer tools you can see, that the amount is updated by `input` type event bubbled on the `document` level, so you need to create that event object and dispatch it to the target `HTMLobjekt` node. Note `<input>` node and `input` type event is completely different things just having the same name.

Comment: can you give an example of how you mean that?
I still can´t find it out by my self.
I would also be interested, how you found that. If you have a good website were i can read that, just send it.

Comment: Use the api: https://docs.gdax.com/

Comment: Nils, are you sure you need _Total (LTC)_ to be updated to automate buying? Seems that is for visualization only. I checked XHR logged after I clicked _Place_ button, and the only value is sent in parameters is the entered amount. See steps 1-5 on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8tdt.png). Most efficient solution is API usage, as @FlorentB pointed.

Answer (score 10):

You need to make sure the page is fully loaded before you take any initiative. I checked for the availability of one such class generated dynamically `OrderBookPanel_text_33dbp`. Then I did the rest what you tried to do. Lastly, you need to `Focus` the target before putting that amount in the placeholder. Applying all of the above, your script should more like below:

```
Sub Get_Value()
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, tags As Object
    Dim tag As Object, ival As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document

        Do: Set tags = HTML.querySelector("[class^='OrderBookPanel_text_']"): DoEvents: Loop While tags Is Nothing
        Do: Set tag = HTML.querySelector("input[name='amount']"): DoEvents: Loop While tag Is Nothing
        tag.Focus
        tag.innerText = 100

        Set ival = HTML.querySelector("[class^='OrderForm_total_']")
        [A1] = ival.innerText
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Output at this moment:

```
0.79139546
```

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete answer, just a direction. Open the webpage https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR in a browser (e. g. Chrome). Click to open context menu on the target element (step 1 on the below screenshot), click *Inspect* (2), from opened  developer tools on the right you can see target element (3), and that there is a bunch of event listeners attached to target object (4). One of the handlers is `input` on the `document` node level. Actually the amount is updated by this event handler, when event is bubbled from `<input>` node. You can easily check that by deleting all other event handlers (click on their <kbd>Remove</kbd> buttons). But if you delete particularly this `input` handler (5) then there will be no update (until you reload the webpage).

[image: F12]

So, to mimic user activity you need to create such `input` event object and dispatch it to the target `<input>` node. Note `<input>` node and `input` control event is completely different things just having the same name.

Tracing event handler execution in IE can be done in debugger. Open IE developer tools (press <kbd>F12</kbd>), go to *Debugger* tab (step 1 on the below screenshot), *Breakpoints* tab (2), click *Add event breakpoint* (3), choose *input* event (4). Now any input event will pause code execution and open debugger window (5).

[image: debugger]

If you try to type in the amount textbox on the webpage, debugger will show event handler function code:

[image: handler]

You may resume execution (<kbd>F5</kbd>), or make step into / over / out. To see event object passed to the function, type `arguments` in console, there is output for standard event handler call after typing manually:

[image: called by typing]

I tested the below test code to trigger that event from VBA:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim oEvt As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"
        Do While .ReadyState < 4 Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        With .Document
            Do While IsNull(.querySelector("div.OrderForm_input-box_XkGmi input"))
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Set oEvt = .createEvent("Event")
            oEvt.initEvent "input", True, False, .parentWindow, 1
            With .querySelector("div.OrderForm_input-box_XkGmi input")
                .Focus
                .Value = "1000"
                .dispatchEvent oEvt
                Stop
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

As a result, absolutely the same actions take place as in case of typing the amount manually. It works without any errors. But *Total (LTC)* isn't updated. Debugger pauses execution as well, and the output for event object is as follows:

[image: called by VBA]

The only difference is that `isTrusted` property is `True` for standard call,
 and `False` for call via VBA. I guess that is why updating is skipped somewhere in the handler code. I tried to trace the entire code execution till event handler completion, but seems that is huge reverse engineering work, which I can't devote time for at the moment.

Currently I'm stucked in my investigations at that point.

Comment: thanks for that. Do you have any further ideas of how i chould trigger this input Event. the only things that i could find was something like this `HTMLobjekt.FireEvent ("oninput")` or, becaus you said it is on the document level, `Ohtml.FireEvent ("oninput")` but none of this worked

Comment: @Nils I have tried to trigger event via VBA, but to no avail, so far. Check answer update.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry could not get to work but have nudged along the problem.

I managed to figure out the correct syntax for creating and raising an event in higher versions of Internet Explorer (thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript#2490876) ) .  I managed to raise an input event for the input box, that followed on from [omegastripes excellent lead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611570/website-does-not-recognize-my-inputs#48674249).

So it works for a local file which I give below that has the same essential structure of the real page.

But when I run the code on the real page it simply does not work and I do not know why.

Where possible I'm feeding javascript into IE for it to execute to miminise issues with the VBA/COM/MSHTML interoperability bridge.  I do this by calling `window.execScript` passing the javascript as a string.

I hope someone can pick up this ball and run it over the goal line.  For me, I have reached the end.

Here is the local html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Programmatically write textbox value" onclick="TestAlert()" />

    <form class="OrderForm_form_25r0u">
        <ul class="OrderForm_trade-type_2QyK4">
            <li class="OrderForm_trade-type-tab_uWGMp OrderForm_active_Di-9p">MARKET</li>
            <li class="OrderForm_trade-type-tab_uWGMp">LIMIT</li>
            <li class="OrderForm_trade-type-tab_uWGMp">STOP</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="OrderForm_toggle_120Ka">
            <li class="OrderForm_toggle-tab_bZZnC OrderForm_buy_38n5g OrderForm_active_Di-9p">BUY</li>
            <li class="OrderForm_toggle-tab_bZZnC OrderForm_sell_3vYRQ">SELL</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="market-order">
            <div class="OrderForm_section_2Znad">
                <div class="OrderForm_section-header_fwFDB">Amount</div>
                <div class="OrderForm_input-box_XkGmi">
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="amount" placeholder="0.00" value="" autocomplete="off" oninput="myOnInputHandler()">
                    <span>EUR</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="OrderForm_order-total_3Mkdz">
            <div>
                <b>Total</b>
                <span>(LTC)</span>
                <b>≈</b>
            </div>
            <div class="OrderForm_total_6EL8d" >0.00000000</div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script language="javascript">
        function myOnInputHandler() {
            print_call_stack();
            alert('you input something');
        }

        function print_call_stack() { console.trace(); }

        function print_call_stack2() {
            var stack = new Error().stack;
            console.log("PRINTING CALL STACK");
            console.log(stack);
        }


        function TestAlert() { setInputBox(document); }

        function setInputBox() {
            try {
                var inputBox = document.querySelector('div.OrderForm_input-box_XkGmi input'); inputBox.value = 100; if (document.createEvent) { var event2 = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); event2.initEvent("input", true, true); event2.eventName = "input"; inputBox.dispatchEvent(event2); }

                return ({ success: true });
            }
            catch (ex) {
                return ({ exception: ex, myMsg: '#error in setInputBox!' });
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the VBA

```
Option Explicit

'* Tools - References
'*      MSHTML      Microsoft HTML Object Library                   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshtml.tlb
'*      SHDocVw     Microsoft Internet Controls                     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ieframe.dll
'*      Shell32     Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation         C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll


Private Function ReacquireInternetExplorer(ByVal sMatch As String) As Object
    Dim oShell As Shell32.Shell: Set oShell = New Shell32.Shell
    Dim wins As Object: Set wins = oShell.Windows
    Dim winLoop As Variant
    For Each winLoop In oShell.Windows
        If "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" = winLoop.FullName Then

            Dim sFile2 As String
            sFile2 = "file:///" & VBA.Replace(sMatch, "\", "/")
            If StrComp(sFile2, winLoop.LocationURL, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Set ReacquireInternetExplorer = winLoop.Application
                GoTo SingleExit
            End If
        End If
    Next
SingleExit:
End Function

Sub test()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLtags As IHTMLElementCollection


    Dim sUrl As String
    sUrl = "C:\Users\Simon\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\HtmlPage1.html"
    'sUrl = "http://localhost:50367/HtmlPage1.html"
    sUrl = "https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR"

    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate sUrl

    If StrComp(Left(sUrl, 3), "C:\") = 0 Then
        Stop '* give chance to clear the activex warning box for the local file
        Set objIE = ReacquireInternetExplorer(sUrl)
    End If
    Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    Set oHtml = objIE.Document

    Do
        '* wait for the input box to be ready
        Set HTMLtags = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("OrderForm_input-box_XkGmi")
        DoEvents
    Loop While HTMLtags.Length = 0

    Dim objWindow As MSHTML.HTMLWindow2
    Set objWindow = objIE.Document.parentWindow


    '* next line would be really useful if it worked because it prints the stack trace in the console window
    '* and we would be able to see the needle in the haystack where te order total gets updated
    '* works on local file but not on https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR  **sigh**
    objWindow.execScript "var divTotal = document.querySelector('div.OrderForm_total_6EL8d'); divTotal.onchange = function() { console.trace(); }"


    '* next line sets the input box and raises an event, works on local file but not on GDAX
    objWindow.execScript "var inputBox = document.querySelector('div.OrderForm_input-box_XkGmi input'); inputBox.value = 100; if (document.createEvent) { var event2 = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents'); event2.initEvent('input', false, false); event2.eventName = 'input'; inputBox.dispatchEvent(event2);  }"


    'get the Total(LTC) to cross check
    Do
        '* wait for the order total div to be ready
        Set HTMLtags = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("OrderForm_total_6EL8d")
        DoEvents
    Loop While HTMLtags.Length = 0

    Dim divTotal As HTMLDivElement
    Set divTotal = oHtml.querySelector("div.OrderForm_total_6EL8d")
    Debug.Print divTotal.innerText & " Total(LTC)"

    Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems `isTrusted` property of event object set to `False` from VBA prevents _Total (LTC)_ updating. Check my answer update.

Comment: @omegastripes : I'll have another go based on your updates, glad to see you got the DOM breakpoints working.  Did you see I tried to get a console trace for when the calculation gets updated?  I agree is huge reverse engineering task.

Comment: Yes, I've tried `console.trace();` feature from your answer too. Generally IE call stack tab may also help while debug.