# Clicking an Angular (ng-click) search button in IE using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, automation, getelementsbyclassname, getelementsbyname

I am new to VBA.  I am trying to click on the "GO" search button after I logged in to a secured website.

I tried many ways to click on the button, but I got no luck.

Here is the inspect element.

```
<button class="button primary pull-right" ng-click="search()" ng-disabled="searchForm.$invalid">
    Go <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
</button>
```

Here is what I have tried.

Method 1

```
Set HTMLDoc = HTMLDoc.class("button primary pull-right").document
Set button = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")(0)   'first button
button.Click

For i = 1 To 5
button.Click
DoEvents
Next
```

Method 2

```
For Each hyper_link In allhyperlinks
If hyper_link.class = "button primary pull-right" Then
       hyper_link.Click
       Exit For
  End If
Next hyper_link
```

Method 3

```
Set allhyperlinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each hyper_link In allhyperlinks
If hyper_link.getAttribute("class") = "search" Then
hyper_link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
```

Method 4

```
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim ie As Variant

For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByName("button")
If oHTML_Element.className = "button primary pull-right" Then
    oHTML_Element.Click
End If
Next
```

Method 5

```
     Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
     With ie
    Do Until .readyState = 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
        ie.document.getElementsByClassName("button primary pull-right").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

End With
```

Method 6

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.document.getElementByClassName("button primary pull-right")(0).Click
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have not given url because it is beyond a login.  That makes solving ten times harder.  Nevertheless some points.

- ng-Click means its running Angular.
- Sometimes it is required to make the control take the focus before simulating the Click event.  [Website does not recognize my inputs [how to fire IE dom event manually from VBA]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611570/website-does-not-recognize-my-inputs-how-to-fire-ie-dom-event-manually-from-vba/48734548#48734548)
- I'd use .querySelector() or .querySelectorAll() to acquire the button because I can use the path at the bottom of the Chrome Development Tools Window.  [VBA - Webscraping - jQuery selectors available with MSHTML's querySelector and querySelectorAll](http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-webscraping-jquery-selectors.html)

Comment: Thanks for spending time to answer my question.  Here is an example. This is from the www.jetblue.com.  If I want to hit the "Find it" button using VBA.  How should I modify the code?  Here is the inspect element.  <input class="piejs" type="submit" value="Find it" ng-click="handleSubmit($event)" ng-hide="type=='bff'">

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim ie          As Object
Dim e           As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "www.jetblue.com"
    Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    For Each e In .document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If e.ID = "email_field" Then
            e.Value = "your email"
        ElseIf e.ID = "password_field" Then
            e.Value = "your password"
        End If
    Next e

    For Each e In .document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If e.ID = "signin_btn" And e.Type = "submit" Then e.Click: Exit For
    Next e
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for spending time on looking into this.  I had no problem to sign in with my log in and password. My question is, how to hit "FIND IT" on the jetblue.com.   The "Find It" button is running Angular.